# How to get user list of given group in AEM6.1

Tags: aem

I have use case like need to fetch all user of given group and then get all the email id to send notification.
Below is my code snippet.

```
public void getUserName() {
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = null;
    try {
        resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        if(null !=resourceResolver ) {
            Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
            resourceResolver = getResourceResolver(session);
            // UserManager userManager =((JackrabbitSession) session).getUserManager();
            UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
            Authorizable authorizable= userManager.getAuthorizable("mygroup");
            org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group group = (org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Group) authorizable;
            Iterator itr = group.getMembers();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Object obj = itr.next();
                if(obj instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User) obj;
                    System.out.println("Name"+user.getID());
                    Authorizable userAuthorization = userManager.getAuthorizable("user.getID()");
                    if(userAuthorization.hasProperty("/profile/email")) {
                        System.out.println("EMailID-----"+userAuthorization.getProperty("/profile/email").toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But at line

```
UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
```

I am getting

> "could not resolve type:
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager".

Note : I am working on AEM6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet of code works just fine in [Groovy Console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console):

```groovy
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager;

def resourceResolverFactory = getService("org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory")
def resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);

def authorizable= userManager.getAuthorizable("everyone");
```

Do you import AEM 6.1 classes in a right way? Example import in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
    <classifier>apis</classifier>
    <!--<classifier>obfuscated-apis</classifier>-->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Tip 1**: `classifier` can have `apis` or `obfuscated-apis` value, depending on your level of access to the jar. [More information.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1914114?start=0&tstart=0)

**Tip 2**:
Please try to avoid administrative resource resolver, [since it's deprecated](http://www.aemmastery.com/2014/12/04/heads-up-getadministrativeresourceresolver-deprecated-apache-sling/).

**Tip 3**:
Adapters and adaptables on your local instance can be always found under following URL http://localhost:4502/system/console/adapters